# JQuery UI Sortable on Bootstrap form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a bootstrap form whose elements are nested in rows. I want for sorting to happen for each element across rows. Currently I have sorting on elements working for the row they are in only.

Is there a way for me to have elements sorted across rows?

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                    <label>Middle name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                    <label>Phone Numer</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                    <label>Date of birth </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $(".row").sortable({ cancel: null });
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connectWith](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith):

> A selector of other sortable elements that the items from this list should be connected to. This is a one-way relationship, if you want the items to be connected in both directions, the connectWith option must be set on both sortable elements.

```js
$(".row").sortable({
    cancel: null,
    connectWith: ['.row']
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
            <label>Middle name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
            <label>Phone Numer</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
            <label>Date of birth </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```